# List of objects that have a list of other objects as one of their parameters

Tags: list, object

I have this object `Object1` defined as `public Object1(String item, List<Object2> obj2)` in a class (whilst `Object2` is defined in another class as `public Object2(String item1, String item2)`)

Next, in the main program, I'm creating a list of `Object1` objects:

```
public static List<Object1> obj1 = new List<Object1>();

List<Object2> obj2 = new List<Object2>();:

obj1.add("first", obj2);
obj1.add("second", obj2);
obj1.add("third", obj2);
```

Next I want to add some objects into `obj2` for every `obj1` specifically:

```
obj1[0].Obj2.Add(new Object2("first","first");
obj1[0].Obj2.Add(new Object2("first","second");
obj1[1].Obj2.Add(new Object2("second","first");
obj1[1].Obj2.Add(new Object2("second","second");
obj1[2].Obj2.Add(new Object2("third","first");
obj1[2].Obj2.Add(new Object2("third","second");
```

Now the problem is that, for example, `obj[0].Obj2.Count` is `6`, and it's the same for `obj[1].Obj2.Count` and so on. How should I populate `obj2` so that each `Obj2` would be different depending on `obj1[]`? For example `obj1[0].Obj2` different from `obj1[1].Obj2` and `obj1[0].Obj2.Count` to be `2`.

Please excuse me if I didn't explain my problem properly or didn't write all the necessary details. Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: What about obj1 will affect the Obj2 property's value?

Comment: Obj2 is always the same, I just want each obj1 to have its own Obj2 list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, you should have a different list for each Object1

```
obj1.add("first", new List<Object2>());
obj1.add("second", new List<Object2>());
obj1.add("third", new List<Object2>());
```

Have you considered using a Map ?